# Oracle: Editing and comparing(diffing) CLOBs

Tags: oracle, diff, clob

I have a table, which has a column of type `CLOB`. Now I wish to compare 2 entries and to have a possibility to edit them. Is there any editor, which can show me differences, for example in a similar way as in `Notepad++` with the plugin `compare`? And I'd like to edit the CLOBs directly from the table in this editor.

Answer (score 1):

DBMS_LOB has a COMPARE routine which will let you identify clobs that are the same (or different)

In terms of *editing* the clobs, you could use SQL Developer to edit them in place.

I don't know of anything directly in any tool that gives you a "visual" diff without extracting them to files first.